# creating a react project

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, visual-studio, project

[prtScn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x35Zc.jpg)
I'm trying to start new react app and I have a problem.
im using visual studio code , and follows the instructions:
in the visual code terminal :

```
create-react-app sali (sali is the name)
npm install 
 node node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js -d -w
```

and then i get this message:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
|
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
|
| // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
```

here is the code:(this is the default code of create react app)
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sali",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

Please, what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to run just `npm run build` or `npm run start` instead of calling wepback directly?

Comment: After a clean `create-react-app` even a `npm start` should be enough. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you wrote in your terminal is

```
> create-react-app sali
> npm install 
> node node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js -d -w
```

With Create-React-App, this is not what you are supposed to do, you should do :

```
> create-react-app sali
> cd sali
> npm run start
```

And you should read [React documentation and tutorials](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) because they will be of a good help !